# Webpack: how add component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, font-awesome, preprocessor

I need to add a [component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fa) (module) to my [configuration](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/webpack-electron-builder-react-sass-conf/blob/master/webpack.config.js). How to do it right?

I get this error:

```
[1] ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
[1] Module parse failed: C:\Users\steko\Desktop\webpack-electron-react-sass-conf\node_modules\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css Unexpected character '@' (7:0)
[1] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[1] | /* FONT PATH
[1] |  * -------------------------- */
[1] | @font-face {
[1] |   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
[1] |   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
[1]  @ ./node_modules/react-fa/lib/index.js 13:0-44
[1]  @ ./src/AwesomeComponent.jsx
[1]  @ ./src/index.jsx
```

This is strange, because I added the style-loader for css. How to fix it?

[git](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/webpack-electron-builder-react-sass-conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VINET You need to add a rule to process CSS files in your webpack conf.

Try adding following rule in your configuration

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the the url loader for the font files in webpack.config

```
{
    test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff',
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff',
  },
  {
    test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?mimetype=application/octet-stream',
  },
  {
    test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
  },
```